# Interpolate each 25 rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I have a 250 by 86 dataframe. I wish to linearly interpolate each 25 rows of each column of this dataframe using the ".interpolate function". This is the code I tried:

```
for i in range(0,25,25):
for x in range(2,len(df.columns)):
    df.iloc[i,x].interpolate(method='linear', inplace=True)
```

which unfortunately is giving me the following error

"AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'interpolate'"

Some help for doing this would very much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In a matrix-like dataframe, `df.iloc[i,j]` returns the value located in i-th row and j-th column. That is why you get this error, you are trying to interpolate a number. See this example:

```py
>>> x = pd.DataFrame(data=[{1:2, 3:4, 5:6},{1:8,3:10,5:12}], index=[1,2])
>>> x
   1   3   5
1  2   4   6
2  8  10  12
>>> x.iloc[0] # first row
1    2
3    4
5    6
Name: 1, dtype: int64
>>> x.iloc[0,1] # first row, second column
4
>>> x.iloc[1,0] # second row, first column
8
```

You don't have to iterate the dataframe to interpolate, [from pandas' interpolate documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

> "Fill the DataFrame forward (that is, going down) along each column using linear interpolation"
>
> [...]

```py
>>> df
     a    b    c     d
0  0.0  NaN -1.0   1.0
1  NaN  2.0  NaN   NaN
2  2.0  3.0  NaN   9.0
3  NaN  4.0 -4.0  16.0

>>> df.interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
     a    b    c     d
0  0.0  NaN -1.0   1.0
1  1.0  2.0 -2.0   5.0
2  2.0  3.0 -3.0   9.0
3  2.0  4.0 -4.0  16.0
```

Use the `axis` parameter to control whether to interpolate along the index (the example above) or along the columns (`axis=1`).

Comment: thanks! Although, I am still not sure how to do every 25 rows. Surely, for that I would need a loop?

Comment: Oh I see. By every 25 rows, do you mean to interpolate only rows [0, 25, 50,...]?

Comment: This `df.iloc[i] = df.iloc[i].interpolate(method='linear')` manually interpolates each row in a loop  (it is the same as `df.interpolate(axis=1)`. 

But you can use `for i in range(0, len(df), 25):` to select the desired rows.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for so I can update my answer